# separate code and configuration in Jenkins

Tags: svn, configuration-management, jenkins, deployment

I was using home build deployment system, but want to move to Jenkins. One problem is that I do not keep app configuration in revision control system for security reasons. What could be a solution to assemble code and configuration for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Just setup another revision control system for configuration. you can set the permission to this second repo to a very limited pool of people. However, without knowing on how/why you keep the configuration info looked down, it is difficult to help you.